# Is "happy with ..." formal?

Tags: formal-language, email

Can I use the following sentence in an email? Is "happy with" formal? if not what are the alternative phrases?

"My supervisor is happy with the attached version of the contract"

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's not informal. This is just the normal phrasing with common words.  There is no need to use anything else.

You might say "approves of" (or "has approved") if approval has been sought and given.

You could use synonyms like "content with" or you could go metaphorical "My supervisor has given their blessing to..." But that is a little silly.

The simple and correct word is "happy"

Comment: @MHSN Happy is a nice, short, simple word. "Formal" usage is not about choosing fancy words when simple words will do; it's just about avoiding some of the usages that are frowned on as "bad grammar" or "slang" words (e.g. "My supervisor is totes psyched about the attached version"). As long as we're not breaking any "rules," there's no reason to choose cumbersome or unclear words.